# Are there any tools to speed up Cocoa development?

Tags: cocoa

I noticed that there is much repeated work to do when creating Cocoa source code.

For example, if I set an instance variable for an object:

```
NSMutableArray *infoArray;
```

I need add code:

```
@property (retain,nonatomic)    NSMutableArray *infoArray;  
@synthesize infoArray;
```

in - (void)dealloc I also need add:

```
[infoArray release];
```

Is there any tool that can automate this, perhaps by automatically paste or copy the source code and add the repeated code at right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out accessorizer for xcode